# How can I add Adobe Pdf viewer in Visual Studio 2019( Asp.net Vb.net Project)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to display pdf file on my screen(web page). So I added "adobe pdf reader" in toolbox (COM) and also added "Adobe Acrobat 7.0 Browser Control Type Library 1.0" into reference. But pdf reader is not showing in my toolbox.
How can I do for displaying pdf on my screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use asp:LinkButton if you don't have any library/external plugin. I recommend you DevExpress if you have to choose one.

Comment: thank you. I used LinkButton and it did work well. I made a reference from this site. https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/PDF-Viewer-ASPNet-Embed-PDF-file-on-Web-Page-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: As you  found out - you can see that you not really using nor care about the Adobe PDF viewer - but are accepting and using whatever the end user has setup on their computer and browser to display the pdf.  As such, you can't use com or ActiveX objects in web land - it just don't work that way anymore.